# Sets of arrays in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, set

After adding numbers to a JavaScript set, the set has (or contains) it:

```
let set = new Set();
set.add(1);
set.has(1);  // true
```

But after adding an array (or a set) to a set, it doesn't have (or contain) it:

```
set.add([0,1]);
set.has([0,1]);   //false
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You'll probably need to pass in the same _exact_ array. Same reason `[0,1] === [0,1] // false`

Comment: Using `[0,1]` twice in your code creates two separate memory objects. Whether a set "has" a certain element is based on identity though, which means: are they the same object in memory? Which is not the case.

Comment: @ChrisG: Might it be the case that Java sets behave differently?

Comment: That's very possible; the difference is that Java is compiled to bytecode while JS is interpreted. Afaik the compilation looks for identical literals in the source and uses a single object for all of them, so similar code will in fact behave differently with Java. (afaik) edit: oopsie, apparently no: https://ideone.com/iMeo9S It's true for Strings though: https://ideone.com/9ykwux

Comment: @Hans-PeterStricker please always assume JavaScript works different to Java (even if they are similar and do work in similar ways). They are not the same language after all.

Comment: @Hans-PeterStricker In Java, objects can have an `.equals()` and `.hashCode()` methods in addition to `==`. The equality operator will compare objects by their reference. This is also how JS sets work. But Java sets use the `.hashCode()` method. IIRC few implementations also allow for custom comparison to be supplied to the set, instead of the one on the members. At any rate, the point is that the comparison is different.

Comment: Btw, the explanation for the difference (in Java) is that Arrays are mutable but Strings aren't. So using a single object for identical string literals is safe, while for arrays it wouldn't be at all.